# How can I use multiple IP-addresses, multi-homing, on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ip-address, multi-homed

Is there an easy way to set up multiple IP-addresses (multi-homing) for a Windows 7 machine?

Today the machine is on a LAN and the IP-address is allocated by DHCP, I can change to static address allocation if needed.

I have seen multi-homing been done via Registry-manipulations on Windows XP, is there any easier way to do it on Windows 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must switch to static addressing first. Then go to *Network and Sharing Center - Change adapter settings*. Right click on your network adapter, choose *Properties*, double-click on "Internet Protocol (IPv4)" (or IPv6), then click *Advanced*, and you will be allowed to add multiple IP addresses.

This works on Windows XP too, except it only allows IPv4 to be configured via the GUI (command-line is needed for IPv6).

Comment: So there is no way to assign both a static and dynamic/DHCP address at the same time?